# Enforce low process ID for specific linux program

Tags: linux, process

I need to run a program which is incompatible with high process IDs (>16 bit) (see https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/607517) and which can not be changed to a different compiler version (only available as binary) on a system with high process IDs enabled (pid_max=4194303). This process always crashes if it gets a PID > 65535 when output is redirected (for example by Jenkins or CTest).

Is there a method to enfore a low process ID for this specific program while the system is still configured to use high IDs? This has to be done by a normal user without root access (changing /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max before/after the start is not a solution).

Side question: Could a RedHat Enterprise Linux/CentOS system with pid_max>4000000 be considered as "RedHat compatible" or would this be an incompatible change?

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing, and I can't imagine how it could be done. When you run a program, you first fork a process, which assigns the PID, and then call `exec()` to load the program into it. It doesn't know what program will be running before the PID is assign.\

Comment: You are right, @Barmar: So basically the fork already needs to be limited to low process IDs...

Answer (score 0):

When you fork, you have to identical processes but for the pid. You can exit the parent process and have a new pid then (but the process is also a daemon then). If you iterate that you can start as soon as your pid is small enough. This might take a while, though. On my system it was like 2500 pid/second. Which means to cycle once around you need to wait like 1600 seconds.